# Position:fixed one element cover other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

On my site few element getting the same class after scrolling page down. It's running by JavaScript. The problem is that the elements get: 
    `position:fixed; top:0; left:0;`
so one element covering another element when I scroll down, what should I do to make each elements next to each other when I scroll down?

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z0hLzw4g/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height of the first element and give it as top to the second element

```
$('.inelementthree').css({
   position: 'fixed',
   top: $('#elementone').height(),  // instead of top:'0'
   left: '0',
   padding: '0',
   width: '100%'
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sticky;
  setTimeout(function() {
    sticky = $('#elementone').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > sticky)
        $('#elementone').css({
          position: 'fixed',
          top: '0',
          left: '0',
          padding: '0',
          width: '100%'
        });
      else
        $('#elementone').css({
          position: '',
          top: '',
          left: '',
          padding: '',
          width: ''
        });
    });
  }, 100);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var sticky;
  setTimeout(function() {
    sticky = $('.inelementthree').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > sticky)
        $('.inelementthree').css({
          position: 'fixed',
          top: $('#elementone').height(),
          left: '0',
          padding: '0',
          width: '100%'
        });
      else
        $('.inelementthree').css({
          position: '',
          top: '',
          left: '',
          padding: '',
          width: ''
        });
    });
  }, 100);
});
```

```css
.col-sm-4 {
  width: 33.33333%;
  float: left;
}

.body {
  height: 1000px
}

.inelementthree {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f00
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full">
  <div class="abovetop">
    <span id="elementone">This is element one</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="elementtwo">This is element two</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="elementthree"><span class="inelementthree">This is element three</span></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="elementfour">This is element four</div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not solution for me becouse I have many items, much more then 2, so I must find a way to put theme in the same line if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <section class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <ul>
        <li>This is element one</li>
        <li>This is element two</li>
        <li>This is element three</li>
        <li>This is element four</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

#### jQuery

```
var elements = $('ul');
$(document).scroll(function () {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() >= elements.height()) {
    elements.addClass('after-scroll');
  } else {
    elements.removeClass('after-scroll');
  }
});
```

You can take a better look at https://jsfiddle.net/iszwnc/8gdttef4/ and if it is the right answer I will work harder on documenting it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just updated your fiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/uh71mrvb/

maybe removing left:0;
and changing width to "auto" when the element is fixed might do the trick?

good luck!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sticky;
  setTimeout(function() {
    sticky = $('#elementone').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > sticky)
        $('#elementone').css({
          position: 'fixed',
          top: '0',
          left: '0',
          padding: '0',
          width: '100%'
        });


else
        $('#elementone').css({
          position: 'relative',
          top: '',
          left: '',
          padding: '',
          width: ''
        });
    });
  }, 100);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var sticky;
  setTimeout(function() {
    sticky = $('.inelementthree').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > sticky)
        $('.inelementthree').css({
          position: 'fixed',
          top: '0',
          padding: '0',
          width: 'auto'
        });
      else
        $('.inelementthree').css({
          position: '',
          top: '',
          left: '',
          padding: '',
          width: ''
        });
    });
  }, 100);
});
```